# Getting rid of unwanted keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `dict1`; each value is a list of strings. If all elements in this list of strings contain `'my_string'`, I don't need this particular key. I've come up with this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict2 = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in dict1.iteritems():
    for list_element in value:
        if 'my_string' not in list_element:
            dict2[key] = dict1[key]
```

It does work but I'm sure there is a better way of doing it. (And I'd prefer not to create another dictionary, which happens in the code above, but it's not really important.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify a `dict` while iterating over it. You either need to create a new `dict` by filtering the old, or create a temporary object of some kind to iterate over:

(1) Create a new `dict` with the filtered results:

```
dict1 = {k:v for (k, v) in dict1.iteritems() if all('my_string' in e for e in v)}
```

(2.1) Create a temporary `dict`:

```
for k, v in dict1.copy():
    if all('my_string' in e for e in v):
        del dict1[k]
```

(2.2) Create a temporary `list` of key-value `tuple`s:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if all('my_string' in e for e in v):
        del dict1[k]
```

(2.3) Create a temporary `list` of keys:

```
for k in dict1.keys():
    if all('my_string' in e for e in dict1[k]):
        del dict1[k]
```

So, how do you decide between them?

Well, 1 is easiest to reason about, because it has all of the benefits of mutation-free code. But 2.1-2.3 are probably more straightforward for a novice programmer. Usually, that distinction is the most important one.

If you're worried about memory usage, obviously 2.3 is better than 2.1-2.2, because it generates a much smaller temporary object. But what about 2.3 vs. 1? That depends on two things: First, how big is a `list` of all of your keys compared to a `dict` of just your remaining items? Second, how much space is gained by building a smaller hash table from scratch instead of shrinking a larger one? Usually, you don't get *any* benefit from the latter, because Python doesn't shrink the hash table at all… but if it matters, you need to test with your use cases on your platform, and see what happens.

If you're worried about performance, it's pretty similar to memory usage. 2.3 vs. 1 are the obvious contenders, and 1 will be better unless you're keeping most of the `dict` around—but again, if it matters, you need to measure for yourself.

Finally, note that the above is for Python 2.7, which is what (as a guess) you seem to be using. In 3.x, `items` and `keys` both return iterators over the existing `dict`, so you need to do `list(dict1.items())` and `list(dict1.keys())` to make the copying explicit.

Answer (score 2):

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    if all('my_string' in e for e in value):
        del dict1[key]
```

Note: be careful not to use `iteritems` and delete from the same dict. `items` are fine, it makes a copy.

Comment: Should be `all`, not `any`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you can just use a dictionary comprehension, if that's available in your version:

```
filtered = {k:v for k,v in d1.items() if all(e == 'my_string' for e in v)}
```

This assumes you don't mind making a second dictionary that is a filtered copy of the first.